# How to display both points and edges in MeshLab?

Tags: mesh, meshlab

I'm new to MeshLab, but can anyone tell me how to display BOTH points AND edges? Now, I can only choose either one, not both. I'm using a .ply file to load the mesh. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Show edges using the usual toolbar button and then activate the *Show Vertex Dots* decoration (in the menu *Render->Show Vertex Dots*).

Optionally, activate the layer side dialog and in its lower part you will see the options for this decoration where you can change the dot size.

Comment: Thanks AloopingIcon! Render->Show Vertiex Dots solve the problem! However, the dots are now all in black. Do you know how to show the original color of the dot (and hopefully edge) as stored in the .ply file in this dot-and-edge view?

Comment: Probably too late to be helpful, but white to black change you experienced is probably due to turning on the "Light." Click the lightbulb icon on the toolbar and you should have your original colored points back.

Comment: Please, mark this answer as "selected" to close the question and show it as solved.